# Lion Mail "Show Format Bar' button missing

Tags: macos, mail.app

In Lion Mail there is supposed to be a "show format bar" button at top right of a new mail window. It is not there for me. How can I get it to show?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to customise the toolbar and add the format button.

Drag the format button to the bar:
[image]

And when you compose a new message, you can click on the format icon:
[image]

And the bar will appear.

Comment: This is the correct answer. It would have even been better to say "you have to customize the toolbar using View > Customize Toolbar" because this was not immediately obvious. Nevertheless, thanks!